# How to modify file permissions

Tags: macos, terminal, command

I made script (steamBlob.command), which deletes the file 
/Users/myuser/Library/Application\ Support/Steam/ClientRegistry.blob
... and another one. The code is

```
chmod +x steamBlob.command
rm -Rf /Users/pipsqueaker/Library/Application\ Support/Steam/ClientRegistry.blob 
rm -Rf /Users/pipsqueaker/Library/Application\ Support/Steam/AppUpdateStats.blob 
rm -Rf Users/pipsqueaker/Desktop/theRace.odt
```

However, when I double click this to run it a windows pops up showing the message

The file “steamBlob.command” could not be executed because you do not have appropriate   access privileges.

I've tried going into finder and changing all the permissions to "read and write", but the problem persists. Should I be running this as sudo? it'd be nice if someone could give me some detailed steps on how to clear this up

thanks,

-me

Comment: Who is the owner of the steamBlob.command file?

Comment: no idea what you mean. sorry

Comment: Sorry, but a lot of the time when I ask questions the solutions in the comments don't help. I'll try though. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have execute access on the steamBlob.command file. From terminal you can "chmod +x 'filename'" (use the appropriate value for 'filename'). Plus, I'd use ".sh" for the extension AND make the first line "#!/bin/tcsh" (or whatever shell for which the script is written).

Comment: What value should I pass into chmod, the file name?