# Cannot make changes to ionic.app.css after installing Sass?

Tags: macos, permissions, terminal, sass, adobe-edge

I'm working on an app in ionic, and would like to customize the .CSS file that was generated by Sass after installing. When I open the .CSS file in my editor (Edge Code), make changes, and try to save the file I get:

...The permissions do not allow you to make modifications.

I imagine there is a command I can type into the Terminal to grant this permission, but now sure what. I'm pretty new to using CLI tools. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: Terminal for which OS?

Comment: My laptop is running Yosemite

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676191/how-to-modify-file-permissions

Comment: Thank you. I tried the command sudo chmod +x www/css/ionic.app.css and entered my password, but nothing happened. When I look at the file in the terminal, it says root next to it instead of my username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: you should not edit the generated css files directly, since your changes will get overwritten.

Nevertheless, to fix the permission issue, you need to set your user account as the owner of the file:

```
sudo chown yourUser www/css/ionic.app.css
```

Just replace *yourUser* with the short user name of your account.

Answer (score -1):

You can make changes(adding new class element styles or customize ionic default style) on scss/ionic.app.scss.
Late but can be important for someone!